# React js and axios POST request sends empty array

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

When I try to post to the other server using axios 
it first sends OPTIONS request then POST.
When I check network connection 
it sends object with fields I wanted 
just the this.state.array is empty.

It's weird beacuse when I debug it just before sending it is not empty?

```
var someProperty="value";

const objectToSend = {
  content: this.state.myArray,
  prop1: someProperty,
  abc:'3456'
};

console.log('user obj------->',objectToSend); //  everything is fine { content: Array(0), prop1: 'value', abc:'3456'}

  axios.post('http://server:8544/api/post', objectToSend)
          .then(function (response) {

            }) //  it sends { content: [], prop1: someProperty, abc:'3456'}
```

//method which updates state of array(or key value pair to be precise)

```
  processAnswer(q, a) {

var key = q;
var val = a;

this.state.myArray['\"'+key+'\"'] = val;
```

}

Comment: Nothing shown would tell us why it shouldn't be empty

Comment: Please share where you're updating your state. This would be helpful

Comment: Is the `POST` request going or is it stopping after `OPTIONS` request?

Comment: Child components receive method from main class an then they send those changes back to the method which is located  in the same class where post occurs it's called processAnswer @MithunGS Post goes on and gets 200 back , other values except array are set succesfully

Comment: where are you setting values to the `array`?

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

myArray was defined as array under state
myArray : []

problem was that axios didn't recognize that and although state of myArray  before post was ["key":"value","key2":"val2"] after submiting it would be sent like this myArray : []

So I changed initial state to myArray : {} 
and now it sends key-value object {"key":"value","key2":"val2"} instead of array and everything works fine